# Select values in an array with specific conditions in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

In PHP I have an array that looks like below, but with a lot of more values. I want to select only few values of this array with this conditions : 5 spares of each series with the minimum price. I have done something in my application but it seems very complicated for this simply condition.
Do you have any idea that can help me to do this the more simply possible?

```
[0] => spare
    (
        [price] => 156
        [name] => alpha
        [serie] => green
)
  [1] => spare
        (
        [price] => 205
        [name] => beta
        [serie] => green
) 
[2] =>spare
    (
        [price] => 276
        [name] => gamma
        [serie] => red
)
[3] => spare
    (
        [price] => 207
        [name] => zeta
        [serie] => green
)….
```

Comment: use usort() and then array_slice().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following steps.

1. Create multiple arrays by serie from that above array.
2. Sort each array by the price. You can get help from this link to short the array. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)
3. Display first 5 element from each array or you can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to get first 5 element.

Answer (score 1):

sort array by usort  and anonymous function and get a slice of needed elements

```
   usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['price'] - $b['price'];
    });
    $output = array_slice($myArray, 0, 5);
```